# mapping all possible string value from nested object into an array asumming key and structure is unknown

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, underscore.js, lodash

helloo,,

i'm trying to retrieve all possible string value from user who signup with linkedin..result is json format,,,

note that one call from one user will get different result with another user.. for example..:

once upon a future time,,,a user sign up my app with linkedin,, after i get access token,, i make a call to linkedin api and get this json result:

```
{
  "firstName": "First Name 1",
  "headline": "Headline 1",
  "id": "MMk56SU",
  "industry": "Education",
  "lastName": "Last Name 1",
  "pictureUrl": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/0_0FVMABigi5VY-wfOsimN0hTy6qn0-om7KFGcqGuy8qWY-Vj7JAG4shGykPWCAejmJAhBJ5Dp7_VOlmK7KN05J_8ro_VxlaMCzN0s-Cvj3Cf1U4COMLWqt9U2E9h74aaPycUvvK",
  "positions": {
    "_total": 1,
    "values": [{
      "company": {"name": "My Lovely College"},
      "id": 5960817,
      "isCurrent": true,
      "title": "Student"
    }]
  }
}
```

the question is: how do i turn that json into an array of string contained only value like this:

```
[
"First Name 1","Headline 1","MMk56SU","Education","Last Name 1","https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/0_0FVMABigi5VY-wfOsimN0hTy6qn0-om7KFGcqGuy8qWY-Vj7JAG4shGykPWCAejmJAhBJ5Dp7_VOlmK7KN05J_8ro_VxlaMCzN0s-Cvj3Cf1U4COMLWqt9U2E9h74aaPycUvvK","My Lovely College","Student"
]
```

after that, other user sign up,,, i make a call again,,, and then i get this result

```
{
  "firstName": "First name 2",
  "headline": "Headline 2",
  "id": "DsadDSsa",
  "industry": "Education",
  "lastName": "Last Name 2",
  "location": {"name": "Some Country"},
  "summary": "my summary"
}
```

the question is: how do i turn that json into an array of string contained only value like this:

```
[
"First name 2","Headline 2","DsadDSsa","Education","Last Name 2","Some Country","my summary"
]
```

after that, the other user sign up,,,etc,etc,,

the key and structure of json result from one user with another will be varied,,,so better to assume key and structure is unknown

i just need to retrieve string value,,, so number and boolean value should be excluded,,,

solution from vanilla js or lodash or underscore or jquery are welcome...

thank You so muchh,,,

Comment: Some effort on your part, showing what you have tried with the problem/s you experienced is required.

Comment: you can use `_.pluck` method of underscore js.

Comment: @KunalKakkad i considered `pluck` but it required key,,,,so it can't be applied in this situation,,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @Xotic750 that it would be nice to see what you have attempted on your own. However, here is a solution. It is a recursive function without any need for a library such as lodash.

```
function stringValues(obj) {
  var strings = [];

  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
    var value = obj[key];

    if (typeof value === 'string') {
      strings.push(value);
    } else if (typeof value === 'object') {
      strings = strings.concat(stringValues(value));
    }
  });

  return strings;
}
```

Fortunately, we don't even need to make a special case for when `value` is an array, because arrays are objects in JavaScript, so they will be handled by the `else if` block along with plain objects.